# How to intercept double click event on a folder on osx?

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder

experts. what I want is like this: I create a folder named `RootDir`, then I double click the folder in Finder , I hope I can intercept the action and trigger specific action such as mounting this `RootDir` to another folder named `MountDir` and then open `MountDir`, not `RootDir`.

How should I do it (Using objective-c)? 
my platform is **mountain lion (osx10.8)** and I've tried using **fsevent** to monitor, but i don't think i can catch the action of folder open/close....
And is it the only way for me to use Finder injection to achieve this function?
any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate AppleScript scripts with folders. Take a look at [Folder Actions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html)

> A Folder Action script is executed when the folder to which it is
>   attached is opened or closed, moved or resized, or has items added or
>   removed.

Comment: AppleScript does do the trick -- can intercept the double-click event, but it can not block the system default event. say, user double click folder A, I hope this leads folder B to be opened while folder A remains status quo. Now A & B are all opened...that's not what i want:(, anyway really appreciate your help.

Comment: I am adding special extentiion to a folder and hoax os it's a file, that's my solution, hope useful to somebody else.